# Google Data Studio - Use of User Defined Functions (UDFs)

Tags: user-defined-functions, looker-studio

Basic Question: Does Google Data Studio allow calling a SQL User Defined Function (UDF) within a Custom Query data source?

My UDF works great in BigQuery. The exact same code (SQL call to a UDF) fails when creating a report to leverage this data source/code.

The following error is encountered:
Data Set Configuration Error Data Studio cannot connect to your data set.
Failed to fetch data from the underlying data set
Error ID: 53979666

Comment: I'm having the same problem....

Answer (score 0):

+1 to the question, looking for a better solution, too.

My current walkaround is far from ideal, but perhaps could be good enough for someone:

1. scheduled query that executes and materialises data
2. datastudio on top of table created in step 1

Answer (score 0):

Though you can't create a user-defined function in a Data Studio custom query, you can define a UDF in BigQuery and use it in the custom query.

Source: https://www.anvilinsights.com/video/user-defined-functions-udf-in-custom-query