# Bigquery: Match IP address to IP CIDR in another table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am referring to this article in order to lookup IP addresses to country:
https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/geolocation-with-bigquery-de-identify-76-million-ip-addresses-in-20-seconds

However, the public data set: fh-bigquery.geocode.201806_geolite2_city_ipv4_locs is no longer available. So I had to import my own look up table.

I have 2 tables in Bigquery:

```
Row| IP_CIDR (String)| Country_Code
-------------------------
 1 | 160.181.205.0/24| ME 
 2 | 197.157.224.0/24| SL
 3 | 196.32.200.0/21 | CF
 4 | 160.181.224.0/24| SI
...
```

has 400K rows in BQ

and

```
Row| IP (String)     
-------------------------
 1 | 160.181.205.222 
 2 | 197.157.224.123
 3 | 196.32.200.33
 4 | 160.181.224.44
...
```

has 10k rows in BQ

How can I match the IP address to the IP_CIDR in another table such that the result would be:

```
Row| IP (String)     |Country_Code
-------------------------
 1 | 160.181.205.222 | ME
 2 | 197.157.224.123 | SL
 3 | 196.32.200.33   | CF
 4 | 160.181.224.44  | SI
...
```

and null if IP not found in IP_CIDR

This is the original query recommended by the article:

```
WITH source_of_ip_addresses AS (
  SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(contributor_ip, 'xxx', '0')  ip, COUNT(*) c
  FROM `publicdata.samples.wikipedia`
  WHERE contributor_ip IS NOT null  
  GROUP BY 1
)

SELECT country_name, SUM(c) c
FROM (
  SELECT ip, country_name, c
  FROM (
    SELECT *, NET.SAFE_IP_FROM_STRING(ip) & NET.IP_NET_MASK(4, mask) network_bin
    FROM source_of_ip_addresses, UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(9,32)) mask
    WHERE BYTE_LENGTH(NET.SAFE_IP_FROM_STRING(ip)) = 4
  )
  JOIN `fh-bigquery.geocode.201806_geolite2_city_ipv4_locs`  
  USING (network_bin, mask)
)
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
create temp function SubnetToRange(CIDR string)
returns struct<start_ip string, end_ip string>
language js as '''
  var beg = CIDR.substr(CIDR,CIDR.indexOf('/'));
  var end = beg;
  var off = (1<<(32-parseInt(CIDR.substr(CIDR.indexOf('/')+1))))-1; 
  var sub = beg.split('.').map(function(a){return parseInt(a)});
  var buf = new ArrayBuffer(4); 
  var i32 = new Uint32Array(buf);
  i32[0]  = (sub[0]<<24) + (sub[1]<<16) + (sub[2]<<8) + (sub[3]) + off;
  var end = Array.apply([],new Uint8Array(buf)).reverse().join('.');
  return {start_ip: beg, end_ip: end};
'''; 
select IP, Country_Code
from table2
left join (
  select IP_CIDR, Country_Code, SubnetToRange(IP_CIDR).*
  from table1
)
on net.ipv4_to_int64(net.ip_from_string(IP)) 
  between net.ipv4_to_int64(net.ip_from_string(start_ip)) 
  and net.ipv4_to_int64(net.ip_from_string(end_ip))
```

if applied to sample data as in your question

```
with table1 as (
  select '160.181.205.0/24' IP_CIDR, 'ME' Country_Code union all
  select '197.157.224.0/24', 'SL' union all
  select '196.32.200.0/21', 'CF' union all
  select '160.181.224.0/24', 'SI' 
), table2 as (
  select '160.181.205.222' IP union all
  select '197.157.224.123' union all
  select '196.32.200.33' union all
  select '160.181.224.44' 
)
```

the output is

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help @Mikhail. My tables are as big as 400,000 rows in the first table and around 10,000 rows in the second table. Is there a way I can write the query without listing each IP value as you had for the 4 IP addresses?

Comment: Those 4 IP Addresses is just for you to test. In reality just ignore them and use your tables! That simple! Please try and confirm

Comment: I am getting a syntax error: "Syntax error: Expected end of input but got "-" at " the 2 FROMs where I indicate the tables names. My table names have got "-" in them (e.g. projectid.dataset.table-1)

Comment: Use ticks around your table names!

Comment: Thanks @Mikhail. I am trying to connect the result of this query to datastudio in order to plot a geo map. However, because of the create function, I am unable to link it to a geo map. The error is "Syntax error: Expected \"(\" or keyword SELECT or keyword WITH but got keyword CREATE [at 2:1]\ncreate temp function SubnetToRange(CIDR string)\n^; Error while initializing the model: projects/xxx/locations/xxx/models/xxx" Same problem that others have highlighted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62959891/google-data-studio-use-of-user-defined-functions-udfs Do you have a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

you can use a query like below

```
    WITH table2 as (
    SELECT 1 as Row, '160.181.205.0/24' as IP_CIDRString,'ME' as Country_Code
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 4 as Row, '160.181.224.0/24' as IP_CIDRString,'SI' as Country_Code
)
, Table1 as (
SELECT 1 as Row,'160.181.205.222' as IPString
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2 as Row,'197.157.224.123' as IPString
UNION ALL 
SELECT 3 as Row,'196.32.200.33' as IPString
UNION ALL 
SELECT 4 as Row,'160.181.224.44' as IPString
),
maptable as
(
select Row, Country_Code, POW(2,(32- CAST(RIGHT(IP_CIDRString,2) AS INT64)))-1 as cidrrange, SPLIT(IP_CIDRString,'.') as IPblocks
from Table2
),
sourcetable as 
(
select Row, IPString, SPLIT(IPString,'.') as IPblocks
from Table1
)


select 
 A.Row
,A.IPString
,B.Country_Code

from 
sourcetable A 
left join maptable B
on A.IPblocks[ORDINAL(1)] = B.IPblocks[ORDINAL(1)]
AND A.IPblocks[ORDINAL(2)] = B.IPblocks[ORDINAL(2)]
AND A.IPblocks[ORDINAL(3)] = B.IPblocks[ORDINAL(3)]
AND CAST(A.IPblocks[ORDINAL(4)] AS INT64) BETWEEN 0 AND cidrrange
```

query results
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help @Dhruv. My tables are as big as 400,000 rows in the first table and around 10,000 rows in the second table. Is there a way I can write the query without listing each IP value?

Comment: @dcs555 https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data

Comment: @DhruvJoshi Imho your solution only works if you have /24-subnets....